# SQL Server 2012 AFTER INSERT trigger when inserting multiple rows

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, sql-server-2012

I'm using the search function in stackoverflow, but I can't find the answer for my problem. But I'm sure I cannot be the first one with this problem.

In my SQL Server 2012 I'm inserting rows and I have an after insert trigger. The inserted pseudo table contains one row with inter alia a timestamp.

With my function the timestamp result a dataset between 1 and x rows, on row for each quarter of an hour. With an cross join i have an multiple row dataset trying to insert into a target table.

To keep in mind:
With an insert of one row in my source table I fire my trigger. The inserted table contains one row. I try to insert multiple rows in the target table.

Error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The code

```
  -- Insert statements for trigger here
DECLARE @state_time DATETIME,@end_time DATETIME
SET @state_time =
    (SELECT state_time from inserted)
SET @end_time =
    (SELECT end_time from inserted)

BEGIN TRY

       INSERT INTO t_Duration
          SELECT
    i.interval
    ,t1.call_id
    ,t1.agent_id
    ,t1.service_id
    ,t1.state
    ,i.duration
         FROM
             (SELECT * 
              FROM myFUnction(@state_time, @end_time, 15)) AS i -- here i get more than one row
         CROSS JOIN 
             (SELECT * from inserted) AS t1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Why? Is it not possible to insert multiple rows with a trigger? If I copy the `INSERT INTO` and fake the inserted table with an table variable, the insert execute successful.

I searching a while and it looks like I need a cursor. Is this right. there are alternatives?

Do you have a clue for me?

Thank you
Frank

=== edit

I should explain what I'm doing...
I get callrecords with an state, lets say "connect", the call_id and a start timestamp and the endtimestamp.
i have to report the duration. i wrote a table value function with three parameters start, end and the duration of the interval in minutes.

as a result set, i get an dataset with one row per interval. it contains a interval_is (i crate an unique id for each interval since 1970) and the duration if a call overlapping a interval.

the insertet dataset in the source table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| call_id | state | starttime           | endtime             |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 4711    | 4     | 2013-10-31 09:25:12 | 2013-10-31 09:32:24 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

the function results the follwing result:

```
--------------------------
| interval_id | duration |
--------------------------
| 3991333     | 288      |
--------------------------
| 3991334     | 144      |
--------------------------
```

with an cross join a try to insert into target table:

```
---------------------------------------------
| interval_id | state | call_id | duration  |
---------------------------------------------
| 3991333     | 4     | 4711    | 288       |
---------------------------------------------
| 3991334     | 4     | 4711    | 144       |
---------------------------------------------
```

and it fails.

Comment: Is there one (or multiple) common columns between the `myFunction` result set and the `Inserted` pseudo table? I would think you should be able to use a simple join (rather than  a `CROSS JOIN`) here... Also: what exactly does `myFunction` do??

Comment: Furthermore: what row of your `Inserted` table do you think this statement will select? `SET @state_time = (SELECT state_time from inserted)` This is really really bad code - `Inserted` can contain **multiple rows** - which `state_time` and `end_time` are being selected then???

Comment: You say "*The inserted pseudo table contains one row ..*", but it does not, it contains multiple rows.  This is what is causing your `SET = (Select..)` subqueries to fail.

Comment: i edit my question to make clear what i'm doing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - why contains my inserted table more than one row. i just insert one row in my source table? when it contains more than one row, it's clear why the trigger fails. But I don't understand why the inserted table contains more than one row

Comment: @ marc_s - i know the set variable = (select ... from inserted) is bad code and I don't like it too. But i have no other idea hiw i can have the time stamps on both sides of the cross join... do you have an idea...

Comment: At a guess, Do you have recursive triggers turned on?

Comment: @marc_s AND RBarryYoung - your are right man. not the insert faild, the setting of the vars fails. set the var with a fake value without select... will run successfull. so my question changes to - how can i have the variable form one side of a cross join on the other side... i don't like also "SELECT TOP 1..." :-)

Comment: @ RBarryYoung - As far as i know - no

Comment: There are a couple of questions I have here that might clarify to get an answer. What does MyFunction return? Could you end up with a cartesian product when you CROSS JOIN with Inserted? 

BTW, You might be better looping and updating indivdually. I cannot tell as there are some missing pieces.

Comment: i edit my question. Below my edit, i explain how exactly my function works. or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am already uncomfortable to answer my own question, I have received many helpful comments, which have brought me on the right track.

Apologies to all who have written to me about the issue somewhat.

The problem was the setting of vraibeles and not the insert into....

So i change the cross join in the following code.

```
    INSERT INTO t_Duration
    SELECT 
        t.interval
        ,t.call_id
        ,t.agent_id
        ,t.service_id
        ,t.state
        ,t.duration
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            inserted AS i
        CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            fInterval2(i.state_time,i.end_time,15) AS iid
        ) AS ext
    ) AS t
```

that works perfect. 
thanks at all
Frank